# TextBoxButton click event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button, textbox

I use flowing code to create TextBoxButton Control . when I write code in " TextBoxButton_Click" void at main class , it work fine. but when I drag this custom control on form , how can manage click event when I double click on this control ? how can determine user clicked textbox or button that inside textbox?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomControl
{
    public class TextBoxButton : TextBox
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

        public Button mbutton;
        public Button button
        {
            get { return mbutton; }
            set { this.mbutton = value; }
        }
        protected override void OnCreateControl()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(this.mbutton);
            SetRightToLeft();
            base.OnCreateControl();
        }
        private void SetRightToLeft()
        {
            if (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
            {
                mbutton.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
            }
            else
            {
                mbutton.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnRightToLeftChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            SetRightToLeft();
            base.OnRightToLeftChanged(e);
        }
        public TextBoxButton()
        {
            mbutton = new Button();
            mbutton.Width = 20;
            mbutton.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            mbutton.Click += TextBoxButton_Click;
            // Send EM_SETMARGINS to prevent text from disappearing underneath the button
            SendMessage(Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(mbutton.Width << 16));

        }

        private void TextBoxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new events in your custom control that you can access after you put the control on your form.

```
public EventHandler TextBoxClick;
public EventHandler ButtonClick;

// Attach this handler to your TextBox.Click event
private void TextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBoxClick != null)
        TextBoxClick(sender, e);
}

// Attach this handler to your Button.Click event
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ButtonClick != null)
        ButtonClick(sender, e);
}
```

The other method would be to make your TextBox and Button `public`, but that seems like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Windows Forms designer to create a `Click` event by default for the control when programmer double-clicks on a `TextBoxButton` in the form designer, use the `DefaultEvent` attribute.

The code below also demonstrates how to create your own `Click` event, which is raised when the button is clicked.

```
[DefaultEvent("Click")]
public class TextBoxButton : TextBox
{
    public TextBoxButton()
    {
        mbutton = new Button();
        mbutton.Width = 20;
        mbutton.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        mbutton.Click += TextBoxButton_Click;
        // Send EM_SETMARGINS to prevent text from disappearing underneath the button
        SendMessage(Handle, 0xd3, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)(mbutton.Width << 16));
    }

    private void TextBoxButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Raise our own Click event
        OnClick();
    }

    public event EventHandler Click;

    protected void OnClick() {
        var handler = Click;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you add an event handler in the constructor:

```
public TextBoxButton(){
//...
//...
 mbutton.Click += Mbutton_Click;
}

private void Mbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("StackOverFlow");
}
```